# Automating Embedded Webviews in a MAC OSX Native application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, hybrid

I have a MAC OSX native application. Some of the screens in this application is using Webviews.

My specific requirement is to automate this view using Selenium.

Questions that I have:

1. Is it really possible to use Webdriver to automate the Webviews in a native MAC OSX hybrid application?
2. If yes, can someone give an example script?
3. If it's possible to automate, how to identify the elements on this Webview?

I also tried with appium-for-mac for automating, but failed. (Seems like its a known issue as per: [This post](https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac/issues/15)

My current setting for the webdriver setup is:

```
private WebDriver buildDriverInstance(String appiumForMacURL){

    URL remoteAddress = null ;
    try {
        remoteAddress = new URL(appiumForMacURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platform","Mac");
    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(remoteAddress,desiredCapabilities);
    return driver;
}
```

Any direction in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

> If it's possible to automate, how to identify the elements on this Webview?

I have used the [Appium Inspector](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#the-inspector) to find the selector. This gave me an XPATH selector that, while slow, worked well enough. This is unlike [switching context to the WebView](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) in a hybrid app.